# Programmatically Setting localStorage Values for Web Request?

Tags: c#, local-storage, webrequest

How, in C#, can I assign keys and values to the localStorage for a domain, before attempting a web request?

Basically I have a page I want to scrape (via AngleSharp), and the domain has an age verification popup whose results are stored in localStorage.  I want to set that up before attempting the web request.

ie: Key: isAgeVerified  Value: true

Comment: `localStorage` is a user agent feature. You are using `AngleSharp`. They documentation says that it's not supported. https://anglesharp.github.io/docs/Features.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check further into that. Using anglesharp is secondary. Is there a way to do it, using whatever C# web client methods (anglesharp aside)?

Comment: For me local storage and .NET HTTP client together sound strange. It doesn't make sense to implement Local Storage in HTTP client. Probably, you should use Selenium with some browser instead.